# Rails and Padrino ActiveRecord ignores GROUP_CONCAT in .select

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, padrino

ActiveRecord in Rails 3 or Padrino is ignoring `GROUP_CONCAT` inside a `.select`.

I'm trying to figure out why AcitveRecord is ignoring this query:

```
Dvd.includes(:dvd_director, :dvd_producer).
      select(" 
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT dvd_director.director SEPARATOR ', ') AS director
      , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT dvd_producer.producer SEPARATOR ', ') AS producer
      ...
      .where("id = 4")
```

The query gets executed but all the `GROUP_CONCAT`s get ignored and the info is not in the result. This is a simpliefied version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745302/rails-activerecord-way-to-write-this-sql-to-send-it-as-a-json-string) which hasn't been answered.

I read somewhere that you should use `.cacluate` for this, but that gives me an error.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

RAILS 4

I had a similar problem with my query:

```
@project
.fields_numbers_projects
.select("*, GROUP_CONCAT(fields_numbers_projects.dates_project_id) AS dpid")
.group(:group_id)
.each do |fpn|
```

And the result of ActiveRecord was:

```
<#FieldsNumbersProject 
id: 1, group_id: 1, project_id: 1, dates_project_id: 1, fields_project_id: 1, employee_id: nil>
<#FieldsNumbersProject 
id: 1, group_id: 2, project_id: 1, dates_project_id: 1, fields_project_id: 1, employee_id: nil>
```

It had no sign of "dpid" or just GROUP_CONCAT(dates_project_id) in the ActiveRecord result whereas you could use it as **fpn.dpid**.

I got fooled for ten minutes by the ActiveRecord result without trying to print.

Comment: I think I later read that this wasn't supported because AR has no way of knowing which DB technology you're using, so some features are unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I think I later read that this wasn't supported because AR has no way of knowing which DB technology you're using, so some features are unavailable, and apparently `GROUP_CONCAT` is not available to every SQL tech out there.